# Can I merge overlapping intervals this way?

Tags: intersection-theory, interval-arithmetic

Say if I have the following function:

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) \   = \   \left\{  \begin{array}{ll} x^2 + 5x -13, &  \mbox{if $2 \leq x \leq 5$ and $0 \leq y \leq x$}, \\ 0, &  \mbox{otherwise}. \end{array} \right.$

Can I merge $2\leq x\leq 5~$ and $~0\leq y\leq x~$ into $~2\leq y\leq x\leq 5$?

Comment: It may help to sketch out a picture of the region defined by the inequalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. For example, $x=2, y=0$ satisfies the first set of inequalities but not the second.